# Gitlab API how to add hook - tag push events

Tags: api, hook, gitlab

I am trying to add hook to newly created project via Gitlab API, I can add push_events hook, but I can't add push_tag_events, it is not even in documentation, but I can add it via web application. Does anybody know whether is it even possible to add it via API? Version of Gitlab is 6.7.2

Answer (score 1):

There is no trace of `push_tags_events` in the [current code base](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/).
It is actually called `tag_push_events` (in [schema.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/1f1cfc9eba6d9b60decb4fcd0645fcbfd288925f/db/schema.rb#L375))

```
t.boolean "tag_push_events", default: false
```

[`spec/models/web_hook_spec.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/1f1cfc9eba6d9b60decb4fcd0645fcbfd288925f/spec/models/web_hook_spec.rb#L12) does use a

```
#  push_events           :boolean          default(TRUE), not null
```

There is [PR to expose `tag_push_events`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/6651).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I've tried even tag_push_events in the API call, but with the same result. So it seems, that at this point, we cannot add web hook via API call for tag push event, right?

Comment: @Tom yes, it doesn't seem to be available yet.